# How to reload a module in django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I created a file named `search_alg_parallel.py`. Then  I wanted reload this module from another module(another .py file). The problem is that I couldn't directly import the file with the `import search_alg_parallel` command, so I couldn't use the reload functionality.  How can I solve this problem?
I thinks this problem relates to django not python.

This is the `search_alg_parallel.py` file which I want to import from another file which called `views_visual_rfp.py` in same directory.
[image]

This is the `views_visual_rfp.py` which raise an error when I import `search_alg_parallel.py` module, line 34
[image]

This is the `error`
[image]

I want to use `reload()` function in `views_visual_rfp.py` module therefore it is important to me to put `search_alg_parallel` module as an argument in `reload()` function. Like that `reload(search_alg_parallel)`

Comment: how do you import it? what's the error? is it a circular import? explain as much as you can.

Comment: @LeylaKrz, I added more detail information with screenshots, thanks for comment.

Comment: have you tried ```import .search_alg_parallel``` ?

Comment: Yes, it gave SyntaxError when I try that

Comment: it's actually a very basic error. try addressing the module from project's root address: ```from DMP_APP import search_alg_parallel```

Comment: Yes this is the right answer, thanks for your answer I've never used Django it's the first time, my friend got stuck in this problem and I tried to help him